# C# MVC FindView / FindPartialView strange performance issues

Tags: c#, performance, model-view-controller

I'm getting some strange performance issues with FindPartialView(), to debug I have the following code which I run in release mode:

```
var startTime = DateTime.Now;
var view = this.BaseViewEngine.FindPartialView(context, proposedViewPath, useCache);
var timeTaken = DateTime.Now - startTime;

this.log.Write(string.Format("FindPartialView Result: useCache='{0}' proposedViewPath='{1}' TimeTakenMS={2}ms", useCache, proposedViewPath, timeTaken.TotalMilliseconds));
```

where BaseViewEngine is an instance of WebFormViewEngine created at Application_Start.

When not in the cache it generates logs like

```
FindPartialView Result: useCache='True' proposedViewPath='~/Controls/Navigation/TopNavigation.ascx' TimeTakenMs=0ms
FindPartialView Result: useCache='False' proposedViewPath='~/Controls/Navigation/TopNavigation.ascx' TimeTakenMs=1607ms
FindPartialView Result: useCache='True' proposedViewPath='~/Controls/Navigation/FooterMenu.ascx' TimeTakenMs=0ms
FindPartialView Result: useCache='False' proposedViewPath='~/Controls/Navigation/FooterMenu.ascx' TimeTakenMs=0ms
FindPartialView Result: useCache='True' proposedViewPath='~/Controls/Navigation/FooterMenuItem.ascx' TimeTakenMs=0ms
FindPartialView Result: useCache='False' proposedViewPath='~/Controls/Navigation/FooterMenuItem.ascx' TimeTakenMs=1279ms
```

And when it is:

```
FindPartialView Result: useCache='True' proposedViewPath='~/Controls/Navigation/TopNavigation.ascx' TimeTakenMs=0ms
FindPartialView Result: useCache='True' proposedViewPath='~/Controls/Navigation/FooterMenu.ascx' TimeTakenMs=0ms
FindPartialView Result: useCache='True' proposedViewPath='~/Controls/Navigation/FooterMenuItem.ascx' TimeTakenMs=0ms
```

Which wouldn't be so bad, but the problem we're having is that it seems to drop item from cache randomly and often (17 out of 77 log entries just minutes apart). As it can't find it in the cache it runs with useCache=false which often takes a ridiculous amount of time (we've recorded it taking more than 4 seconds).

First of all does anybody know why it takes so long? It's not compiled in debug mode and we're giving it an absolute path so it shouldn't have to search for it. I tried giving it the full filesystem path instead (eg. C:\Web\Controls\Navigation\FooterItem.ascx) but it failed to work at all.

Secondly is there any way to get it to use a custom view cache so at least we can make sure that items stay cached?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Ok so far I've got this and it seems to work for our usage pattern, can anyone think of a good reason not to do this?

```
/// <summary>
/// Optimised WebFormViewEngine to fix performance issue with FindView / FindPartialView
/// </summary>
public class FastWebFormViewEngine : WebFormViewEngine
{
    public override ViewEngineResult FindPartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string partialViewName, bool useCache)
    {
        // If absolute path then no need to search for the view
        return partialViewName.StartsWith("~") 
            ? new ViewEngineResult(this.CreatePartialView(controllerContext, partialViewName), this) 
            : base.FindPartialView(controllerContext, partialViewName, useCache);
    }

    public override ViewEngineResult FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewName, string masterName, bool useCache)
    {
        // If absolute path then no need to search for the view
        return viewName.StartsWith("~") && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(masterName) || masterName.StartsWith("~"))
                   ? new ViewEngineResult(this.CreateView(controllerContext, viewName, masterName), this)
                   : base.FindView(controllerContext, viewName, masterName, useCache);
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using DateTime for profiling your code. You should instead be using a Stopwatch as it has much better resolution.

Comment: As a general point about profiling - DateTime has terrible resolution ( ~15 ms ) - try using `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` instead.